# Cannot get simple shellcode runner to work

Tags: linux, shellcode, gcc

I'm just trying to execute shellcode directly from the command line.  I send a simple 0x90 NOP and get a segmentation fault?

```
root@server:~# gcc shellcode.c -o shellrun -fno-stack-protector -z execstack

root@server:~# ./shellrun `perl -e 'print "\x90"'`
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

root@server:~# more shellcode.c
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        (*(void(*)())argv[1])();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Old buffer overflow is old.

Comment: There isn't a buffer overflow in this question whatsoever.

Comment: You must learn to walk before you can run. It is much easier to learn exploitation of a buffer overflow before you move on to vftable and use after free exploit writing or deal with ASLR and DEP. Despite being an old technique there are plenty of buffer overflows in modern software and embedded devices (internet of things).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Do xor 0 and exit() linux syscall instead of nop since the argv ends with a null byte opcode, thats the cause for segfault

Answer (score 6):

In the proposed example, the program is executing a nop sled consisting  of `\x90`.  After this nop sled executes,  it does not return to main,  and therefore crashes with a `Segmentation fault`.

Consider learning more assembler,  and most importantly,  **use GDB to debug segmentation faults**.